# MobileVLCKit turns off the microphone that was on side LFLiveKit

Tags: ios, swift

I am using LFLiveKit and MobileVLCKit now. If I use LFLiveKit to publish my screen and use MobileVLCKit to play the other person's video, MobileVLCKit takes up all the audio sessions and turns off the microphone that was on side LFLiveKit

So I'm looking for a way to return the input session to LFLiveKit side again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, after we initialize the VLCMediaPlayer we need to give permission for microphone